# how re-exporting the routerModule works

Tags: angular, module

Here is the code snippet I am banging my head with:

```
//app-routing.module.ts

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Assume routes to be a constant containing a array of different routes.

Now the main app module imports and use it like:

```
//app.module.ts

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
   ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeroDetailComponent, HeroesComponent, DashboardComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [HeroService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So I do understand this from the official docs

> Import modules whose public (exported) declarable classes you need to
>   reference in this module's component templates.

Now i don't understand this part:

```
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
exports: [ RouterModule ]
```

Howcome this exported RouterModule gets exported to other modules along with the forRoot configured?

Comment: What is unclear about this lines? "Howcome this exported RouterModule gets exported" - because it's listed in `exports: [...]`.

Comment: so it imports it as RouterModule.forRoot(routes) and exports it as RouterModule. What I do not understand is that how this .forRoot(routes) part also get exported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source of RouterModule.forRoot()`

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a0ae1200936d7d51298c0b332edbfb6eefa73b91/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L144

```
static forRoot(routes: Routes, config?: ExtraOptions): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: RouterModule, // <<<====
      providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        provideRoutes(routes),
        {
          provide: ROUTER_FORROOT_GUARD,
          useFactory: provideForRootGuard,
          deps: [[Router, new Optional(), new SkipSelf()]]
        },
```

you'll see that it adds the module and providers.

If `forRoot()` would only add providers, re-exporting wouldn't work.

When Angular loads imports, it registers providers of imported modules and instantiates them. The RouterModule's constructor injects the router service which causes the routers constructor to be invoked.

Comment: i have a different concern here. i want to understand that when you export RouterModule then how '.forRoot()' with correct routes gets exported along with that...

Comment: I don't think it does, but that's handled by the `imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],` This causes the services to be registered, and they are registered in the root scope anyway. This will only work if `AppRoutingModule` is **not** lazy loaded.

Comment: got it. thanks. last question: why then a re-export is required? we can have just the RouterModule imported directly in the app-module and if we can't then i suspect  that these two lines may have some linkage ;)

Comment: Sure, but it's less verbose for the AppModule where probably a lot of stuff will be registered when the app grows.

Comment: so all the imports in the app-module (bootstrapping module), gets bootstrapped/instantiated/unknown-word along with?

Comment: All global singleton services need to be registered in AppModule (directly or indirectly non-lazy). That's the only way to ensure a single global instance. This is why this builds up over time. Otherwise just import what you actually use in the current module.

Comment: (directly or indirectly non-lazy) : in my case indirectly through imported modules. correct?

Comment: With indirectly I meant the `RouterModule` exported by `AppRoutingModule` and therefore imported indirectly to AppModule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157355/discussion-between-benerd-and-gunter-zochbauer).